# How to filter 2d array in Uiua?

Tags: uiua

In [uiua](https://www.uiua.org) the elements of a 1d array can easily be filtered with `▽ keep`

```
1_2_3_4
▽>2.
[3 4]
```

How can I do the same for a 2d array?

Things I've tried that don't work

```
[1_2_3 4_5_6]
▽>2.
Error: Keep amount must be a natural number or list of natural numbers, but its rank is 2
```

```
[1_2_3 4_5_6]
≡(▽>2.)
Error: Cannot append arrays of shapes [1 × 1] and [3]
```

```
[1_2_3 4_5_6]
>2.
≡▽
Error: Cannot couple arrays with shapes [1] and [3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Uiua Language Tour

> Uiua has what is called a flat array model. Arrays must be rectangular and cannot mix types. However, the `□ box` function can turn any array into a *box* element that can be put in an array with other boxes.

Thus, `□ box` them, so the outer array becomes an array of boxes:

```bash
[1_2_3 4_5_6]
≡(□▽>2.)
```

```
[⟦3⟧ ⟦4 5 6⟧]
```

[Uiua pad](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=WzFfMl8zIDRfNV82XQriiaEo4pah4pa9PjIuKQo=)